# Lines Visible When Blending Raster Layer of Merged Tiles QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, print-composer, style, srtm

After merging SRTM DEM tiles into 1 raster layer, the layer has no visible join lines on the map canvas as below. Multiply blending mode has been applied
[image]

However, when viewed in Layout, there is a visible line as below
[image]

This is not visible if normal blending mode is applied to the layer.
I'm using QGIS 3.28.5

---

Well an not directly an answer, but solves the issue. The line isn't shown when exported as a png file.

Comment: Are your really merging the layers or are you not rather creating a virtual raster?

Comment: Yes I had merged them.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more in detail what exactly where the steps you undertook? Can you maybe share the input rasters?

Comment: After closing and reopening QGIS it isn't happening now - very odd.

Answer (score 2):

Such lines appear where two tiles overlap: 1 pixel width. It appears when you set the layers blending mode to `Multiply`, see screenshot.

When you either merge the rasters or create a [virtual raster](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#build-virtual-raster), the line should not appear. Creating a virtual raster is the easiest way as no real merging takes place - the rasters are just combined in a way as if they were merged.

[image]